# IndexOutOfBoundsException in Android

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a button which moves forward in a list. Usually, it works fine until it reaches the end of the list or if the list has just one item. It gives this error     `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1` when I click next while it is the last item in the list or one-item list. Here is the implementation

```
ArrayList<Items> myFiles = new ArrayList<>();

int position;
    
String path;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    path = myFiles.get(position).getPath();
    if (path != null) {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
       simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
       DataSource.Factory factory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory
              (this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "My App Xoxo"));
       ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory, extractorsFactory).createMediaSource(uri);

       playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
       playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
       simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
 

        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               position++;
               path = myFiles.get(position).getPath();
                         
                 if (path != null) {                                     
                   Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
                   ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
                   MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory, extractorsFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
                    playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

                    playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
                    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
                    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
              
                    } else {

                       Toast.makeText(this, "no items" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

When it is the last item, instead of making the toast "no items", it gives the above error. I have tried different solutions but none have worked so far. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Your attempting to get the path before checking if the position is smaller than the length of the list

Comment: add check if the size of your myFiles array is not more than the position, in that check you can show an message to use or any functional implementation

Comment: but isn't the else block checking if the size of myFiles array is not more than position already?

Comment: Yes, but on the line *below* `position++` you are fetching an item from the array, *before* you do that check. If the position is greater than the list, then what did you expect that line to do?

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you're fetching an item from a collection without ensuring the item's position is valid.

You do:

```
position++;  // INCREASE POSITION
path = myFiles.get(position).getPath(); // FETCH ITEM WITHOUT CHECKING
if (path != null && position <= myFiles.size()) { // NOW CHECKING (too late)
```

Instead, you should:

```
position++; // INCREASE POSITION

if (myFiles.size() < position) { // CHECK FOR BOUNDARIES
   path = myFiles.get(position).getPath(); //FETCH ITEM
}

if (path != null) { // CHECK IF THE ITEM IS VALID
 ...
} else { 
 ...
}
```

**UPDATE**
In anticipation of your comment... yes, you still can get a Null Pointer Exception if `myfiles.get(xxx)` returns `null`. I assume (but you didn't mention) that your `myFiles` is an `ArrayList` of some sort, and in Java, array lists can contain null values.

Take, for example, this simple Java program:

```
import java.util.*;
  
class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList();
    myList.add(null);
    myList.add(null);
    myList.add(null);

    String willBeNull = myList.get(1);

    if (willBeNull == null) {
      System.out.println("Is Null!"); 
    }

    System.out.println(myList.size()); 
    
  } 
}
```

If you run that, the output will be:

```
Is Null!
3
```

So if your items can be null, then you should check before dereferencing them...

```
position++; // INCREASE POSITION

if (myFiles.size() < position && myFiles.get(position) != null) { // CHECK FOR BOUNDARIES and nullability.
   path = myFiles.get(position).getPath(); //FETCH ITEM
}
```

Comment: When I use that method, it gives a warning over get saying `The call to 'get' always fails as index is out of bounds` and gives the same result as before.

Comment: it's ... pseudo-code... what warning and in which line? I'm sure the warning is that `myfiles.get(position)` can return null, so getPath can throw a Null Pointer Exception, but that's "outside of the scope" of your question...

Comment: That would indicate that `myFiles` is probably always null and you haven't initialized it. This is why a minimum, complete example is important.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more context then, because there's not enough code to infer the state of your list/array and therefore to make informed opinions.

Comment: I have updated above hopefully that helps